# Kernel won't boot on start up of first time install "this kernels requires an x86_64 CPU

Tags: kernel, 32-bit

At boot time I get this message:

```
This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU.
Unable to boot- please use kernel appropriate for your CPU
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have a 32 bit processor so you need to use 32 bit (i386) version of Ubuntu

http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ download the i386 version

http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-i386.iso

Or you can use 17.04

http://releases.ubuntu.com/17.04/ubuntu-17.04-desktop-i386.iso

Comment: i looked on my operating system on my laptop and i have a 64-bit operating system or that does not matter at all and i am running  ubuntu on a vm

Comment: @DavidCervantes I dont know what you mean by "i have a 64-bit operating system " ? Windows ? Linux ? Ubuntu is not recognizing your processor as 64 bit and if you think you have a 64 bit processor identify your processor in any OS. If you are running linux, show the output of `lscpu`